# Proper way to "store" CMSampleBuffer or CVPixelBuffer to use later

Tags: ios, rtmp, replaykit

Currently working on `Replay Kit` Upload extension and RTMP streaming. `Replay Kit` works great but it only provide `CMSampleBufferRef` when there is any change on screen, so if user stay on a screen and nothing moves, it stops providing `CMSampleBufferRef`.
I convert the `CMSampleBufferRef` to `CVPixelBufferRef` then push to RTMP. 
Here is the problem. I need to keep pushing the latest CMSampleBufferRef in case Reply Kit doesn't provide any more SampleBufferRef.

I tried many different ways to "store" the `SampleBufferRef` or `CVPixelBufferRef` but no luck so far.

I probably didn't understand the concept of bufferRef and memory related stuffs.